# Formula returns #VALUE! when entered as array

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I've put together an Excel spreadsheet to keep track of employees' time off using an array formula.  The formula works for date ranges that are entered as "mm/dd - mm/dd", but I'd like it to also support single dates "mm/dd".  However, I get a #VALUE! error when one of the cells in the range is of this format, even though the formula supports both formats when not entered as an array formula.

Example:

With the value "11/28" in cell B2, and a table of holidays in B31:B37, the following formula accurately calculates the number of work days as 1.

```
=SUM(IF(ISBLANK(B2),0,(IF(ISERR(FIND("-",B2)),NETWORKDAYS(B2,B2,$B$31:$B$37),NETWORKDAYS(LEFT(B2,5),MID(B2,FIND("- ",B2)+2,5),$B$31:$B$37)))))
```

If the value of B2 is "11/28 - 12/03", the formula returns 4.

I want this formula to work over a range of of cells for each employee, so I expand the range from "B2" to "B2:B10", and enter as the following array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B10),0,(IF(ISERR(FIND("-",B2:B10)),NETWORKDAYS(B2:B10,B2:B10,$B$31:$B$37),NETWORKDAYS(LEFT(B2:B10,5),MID(B2:B10,FIND("- ",B2:B10)+2,5),$B$31:$B$37)))))
```

This formula works fine when every cell in the range is blank or has a date range of "mm/dd - mm/dd".  However, if one of the cells has a single date "mm/dd", it throws a #VALUE! error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no "-" in a given string then the FIND function will return a #VALUE! error for that string.

In general, there are two ways to resolve such issues. One is to include an error trap; the other, slightly longer though perhaps nevertheless preferable (IFERROR clauses are generally best avoided if possible), is to make suitable amendments to the strings being passed to MID and FIND such that this combination of functions does not error, whilst also ensuring that correct results are returned.

One such solution (still array-entered) is:

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B10<>"",NETWORKDAYS(LEFT(B2:B10,5),MID(B2:B10&"- "&B2:B10,FIND("- ",B2:B10&"- ")+2,5),$B$31:$B$37)))
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the clever solution; this solves my immediate problem.  However, I'm still puzzled as to why my use of FIND in my OP does NOT throw an error in a standard function.  It only errors out when array-entered.

Comment: Apologies. I did not notice you actually have an appropriate error clause in there. In that case, the reason is a touch more complex: namely that the value_if_true clause for the IF(ISERR... statement is not being sufficiently coerced to operate over an array of values (sometimes array-entry by itself is not sufficient: see here for more if you're interested: http://excelxor.com/2014/11/04/coercing-array-returns-from-cse-resistant-formulas/). Suffice to say that a simple coercion to numerics would suffice in your case: ...IF(ISERR(FIND("-",B2:B10)),NETWORKDAYS(0+B2:B10,0+B2:B10,... etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the link, and the numeric coercion approach.  All very helpful!